# Summarize X, Y Table

Tags: arcgis-10.1, attribute-table

Here is a table that is a sub-set of the data I am working with, I am trying to use the Summarize Statistics tool to select the X,Y values of the First and Last Addresses.

[image]

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

But I would need the Min_X and Min_Y to correspond to 3 Palisade Basin and the Max_X and Max_Y to correspond to 27 Palisade Basin.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whenever I try to summarize the table with first/last or min/max STREET_ADDR I always get 4 Palisade and 12 Palisade as my values. Why would 3 and 27 not be selected?

Comment: Have you tried using the case field parameter?

Comment: Can you explain why you need the X,Y of the first and last addresses? I think I know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Im trying to get from lat/long and to lat/long associated with each TLID

Comment: In that case, wouldn't running summary statistics with a case field on TLID work?

Comment: One would think. When I sort my address field it doesnt give me 3-27 range like needed. When I sort along the Y field it puts it in the right order. I'm guessing that is because this road runs N-S, so the X value would sort correctly for an E-W road

Comment: Why does sorting matter? If you had the address number split from the street name, and you used advanced sorting, it would work correctly. As it is, sorting a number as a string would place 12,14,17,25,28,3000000,4....etc And yes, that is why sorting by location doesn't work well. Most tools, if not all, run irrespective of any current sorting you have applied.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

Use [Select Layer by Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000) to select all records with a STREET_ADDR of 3 Palisade Basin and then run Summary Statistics on that layer. Repeat for 27 Palisade Basin and then you can append the two tables together.

Comment: Yea I came across that but when I have to do this for multiple millions of records I don't know if I have the time for that.

Comment: Well if this is something you are running on millions of records, I think it's high time you start looking into ModelBuilder/scripting.

Comment: That is my next step, just trying to figure out how to get the results I need on this small set of data before I let the model/script run for hours on the entire set.